# Merge sample-code and code-sample

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

Could someone merge [sample-code](/questions/tagged/sample-code) (27 questions) into [code-sample](/questions/tagged/code-sample) (154 questions) and create a synonym. Also, the tag wiki of [sample-code](/questions/tagged/sample-code) should be copied to that of [code-sample](/questions/tagged/code-sample), which doesn't have one yet.

Comment: What's the point of those tags anyway?

Comment: Someone should call for Trogdor: there is work for him.

Comment: They seems to relate to people asking for example code, e.g. "Can anyone show me how to", or boilerplate code, e.g. "does anyone know of a basic application structure in [some-language]". Not sure if there is any overlap with the code-snippets tag.

Comment: @Chris: So, it's honeypot to easily find questions to close then?

Comment: @UristMcBobby Ok. So what is the process for this? Go through all the questions, vote to close (or edit out the tag) and hope other people stumble on them and vote to close aswell?

Comment: @Chris: I'm not sure if a manual retagging is advisable, as the tag should rather be burned completely. But going through the answers, checking them, improving or closing, is a good start.

Comment: @UristMcBobby I'll have a go a checking and improving the questions. However, regardless of the quality of the questions and the tags themselves, surely `sample-code` and `code-sample` should be merged into one tag?

Comment: @Chris: No...but we have a nice stack with plenty of wood, straw and some gasoline here from our last witc^H^H^H^Hosterfeuer which we can use...oh look, here's even a rope which we can use to tie those tags to the stack!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two tags should be blacklisted.  [tutorial](/questions/tagged/tutorial) is already blacklisted, and these tags are essentially being used in the same way, either as a request for sample code, or as a tag to indicate that sample code is being referred to.  Both uses are unproductive.

Comment: Poke. Any possibility to revisit this?  See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168686/burninate-the-code-sample-and-sample-code-tags