# Burninate the [code-sample] and [sample-code] tags

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I just came across a question that used the [code-sample](/questions/tagged/code-sample) tag, and it made me wonder, "What's the point of this tag, anyways?"  The majority of the cases appear to be people just asking "Give me the codes".

It looks like it was previously asked to [merge the [sample-code] and [code-sample] tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139350/merge-sample-code-and-code-sample), and the accepted answer was that the [tags should be blacklisted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139410/148949), but more than a year later, here we are.  Both tags still exist.

Can we get a burninate on aisle 3?

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as this is marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), I'll just leave this here :)

[image: Burninated.]